# Macro to return all inputs that meet a criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro that reads a cell with an input such as "Ball, 15mm" and then returns all values in column K of a separate table when column A has an input of "Ball" and column C has an input of "15". There will be a number of entries that match this criteria so I want it to list off all matches. I'm finding it hard to work out how a function can read a cell that has 2 distinct pieces of information in it and match that over 2 separate cells. Is there a way to get Vlookup to return multiple inputs?

```
Sub RecordData()

MaxRows = Worksheets("Criteria").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("Criteria").Range("E" & MaxRows + 1) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Worksheets("Criteria").Range("B3"), Worksheets("Generate").Range("E:G"), 2, False)
Worksheets("Criteria").Range("F" & MaxRows + 1) = Worksheets("Criteria").Range("B4")
Worksheets("Criteria").Range("G" & MaxRows + 1) = Worksheets("Criteria").Range("B5")
Worksheets("Criteria").Range("H" & MaxRows + 1) = Worksheets("Criteria").Range("B6")
'Below is the line of code im trying to work on'
Worksheets("Criteria").Range("I" & MaxRows + 1) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Worksheets("Criteria").Range("E3"), Worksheets("BOM").Range("A:O"), 11, True)

Worksheets("Criteria").Range("G" & MaxRows + 2) = "Total"
Worksheets("Criteria").Range("H" & MaxRows + 2) = Application.Sum(Range(Worksheets("Criteria").Range("H2"), Worksheets("Criteria").Range("H" & MaxRows + 1)))

End Sub
```

Comment: "I need a macro" is not really a question.  *Which specific part* of the task is giving you problems, what did you try as a solution, and what happened?  That's pretty much what folks are looking for in a question here.

Comment: The intended user will not be looking at the database. Essentially they are choosing a type and size of item from a combo box and I want the system to tell them potential suppliers of the item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take your two criteria out of a single cell content with `Split()` function:

```
Dim criteria1 As String, criteria2 As String

With Worksheets("Criteria").Range("A1") ' change "Criteria" and "A1" to your actual sheet name and its range address where to find your 'two pieces of information'
    criteria1 = Split(.Value, ",")(0)
    criteria2 = Trim$(Split(.Value, ",")(1)) 
End With
```

`Trim()` is used to get rid of leading space in " 15 mm". Alternatively, if you know for sure that all couples are delimited by a comma and a space you can use `Split(.Value, ", ")`

Answer (score 0):

Using DisplayName's answer i generate something which may help you:

Let's that the data are structure as below in Sheet1:

[image]

**Try:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Criteria1 As String, Criteria2 As String, FullCriteria As String
    Dim Lastrow As Long, Result As Double
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        FullCriteria = .Range("B1").Value
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng1 = .Range("A3:A" & Lastrow)
        Set rng2 = .Range("C3:C" & Lastrow)
        Set rng3 = .Range("K3:K" & Lastrow)

        Criteria1 = Split(FullCriteria, ",")(0)
        Criteria2 = Trim$(Split(FullCriteria, ",")(1))

        Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(rng3, rng1, "=" & Criteria1, rng2, "=" & Criteria2)

    End With
```